# Deleted table in database; how to recreate it using Code First

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

After deleting table X in database, issued update-database command in PackageManagerConsole, and now I get the following error: "Cannot find the object "dbo.X" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions."

Considering this scenario, how to force CodeFirst to create the table from scratch?

Comment: either you have to recreate it manually or force EF to initialize the database again, for example using an additional constructor.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro, does initializing the db again requires drop deleting it first?

Comment: not if you write your own initializer, however that might be a not as simple task.

Answer (score 3):

These are the work around steps that deals with this scenario:

1. delete table from db
2. delete all related stored procedures if any
3. create a new imitation entity/table class with a different/distinct name (ex. BlahBlah)
4. create any configs needed for the new entity inside OnModelCreating method
5. in the PackageConsoleManager, issue an add-migration command
6. open the migration file and replace all BlahBlah words with the old table name
7. Comment or delete the old table class
8. repeat 7 for old configs in OnModelCreating
9. rename the new table class with the old table class name
10. repeat 8 for the new table configs in OnModelCreating
11. in the PackageConsoleManager, issue an add-migration command again
12. if it creates a new migration, replace its content with the old migration created in step 6
13. in the PackageConsoleManager, issue update-database command

Comment: After deleting table in db: use ctrl+r, ctrl+r to rename entity, than `add-migration`, in migration in `Up` leave createTable, in `Down` leave dropTable. `update-database`. One more time `add-migration/update-database` to set keys. And rename and `add;update`. This will save correct migrations if you need to rollback.